# Is there a way to stop the late method when executing Promise.race?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below is a just simple example.

```js
function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, time);
    }).then((e) => {
        console.log(`Wait ${time}ms.`);
        return time;
    });
}

async function main() {
    let r = await Promise.race([
        delay(1000),
        delay(2000),
    ]);
    console.log(r);
}
await main();
```

Output:

```js
Wait 1000ms.
1000
Wait 2000ms.
```

I want to stop the remaining code except the code that was executed first through Promise.race.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Promise as such can't be cancelled - there's no harm in this naive code though - as long as the actual code is written in such a way that there's no side effects of the promise continuing to run (or wait for resolution to be accurate), then you simply don't have an issue

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do something like this would be to put the code that runs conditionally near where you call the Promise.

```js
function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, time, time);
    })
}

async function main() {
    const firstResult = await Promise.race([
        delay(1000),
        delay(2000),
    ]);
    console.log(`Wait ${firstResult}ms.`);
}
main();
```

If the code you want to run conditionally is inside a function - like with your original `delay` function - and the function doesn't explicitly provide a way to change its execution after being called - then no, there's nothing you can do to keep that code from executing.

Most of the time when Promises are involved, no such method exists - though there are exceptions, such as with [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController).